# How to transfer the data after the completion of the second process to the first one?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

I have application X.exe and Y.exe. First, I start server X, after which I have to start Y 20 times and get 20 different PIDs. Due to certain circumstances, I have to run these processes at the same time, so I run X and the script issuing PIDs as processes. I don't understand how to transfer the data generated by the second process to the first one in order to work with them already in it. Here is my code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from multiprocessing import Process


def firstproc():
    process = Popen(
        'X.exe',
        stdout=PIPE)
    while True:
        chunk = process.stdout.readline()
        print(chunk)

def secondproc():
    def getPID():
        return Popen('Y.exe').pid
    return [getPID() for _ in range(20)]

def main():
    p1 = Process(target=firstproc, args=())
    p2 = Process(target=secondproc, args=())
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The first process runs indefinitely

Comment: Your question is not very clear. We don't know why there are 20 process ids. We don't know why or what or when one of them needs to send something to somebody. Please click [edit] and clarify. Thank you.

Comment: And why can't you just start the second process first if the first process/processes (?) need the result from the first?

Comment: And if one process needs the results of the other, why are you even trying to run them in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a process1 stdout line in any process2 stdin you can use this code:

```python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread, Lock

class Processes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p1: Popen = None
        self.p2: Popen = None
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.lock2 = Lock()
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.lock2.acquire()
        self.p2_run = True

    def firstproc(self):
        self.p1 = Popen(
            'X.exe',
            stdout=PIPE)
        while self.p2_run:
            line = self.p1.stdout.readline()
            self.lock2.acquire()
            if self.p2_run:
                self.p2.communicate(line)
            self.lock.release()

    def secondproc(self):
        def getPID():
            self.p2 = Popen('Y.exe', stdin=PIPE)
            self.lock2.release()
            self.lock.acquire()
            return self.p2.pid
        pids = []
        for _ in range(8):
            pids.append(getPID())

        self.p2_run = False
        self.lock2.release()
        return pids

def main():
    t = Processes()
    p1 = Thread(target=t.firstproc, args=())
    p1.start()
    p2 = Thread(target=t.secondproc, args=())
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I use threading to synchronize processes to write in stdin and to read stdout.